# ckEditors UploadAdapter not set ImageSource

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, ckeditor5

I am using the ckEditor and the CostumAploadAdapter on my Website.
I want to create sort of a EMail-Client for my WebSiteUsers.
When I insert an image in my ckEditor, the image is uploaded to the server via the UploadAdapter and the image is displayed in the editor.
But when I look at the content of the sended text at server-side it only contains `"<figure class="image"><img></figure>"` for every image. Not the name of the image or the location on the server.
I tried to set the imageName explicitely in the load-Listener of the Adapter (for testing purposes only) but without success.

Does someone has an idea why the Upload Adapter is not insert the correct data or where I have to manipulate the Upload Adapter so that it does what it should do ?

Here is the code of my uploadAdapter:

```
class MyUploadAdapter {
    constructor( loader ) {
        // The file loader instance to use during the upload.
        this.loader = loader;
    }

    // Starts the upload process.
    upload() {

        return this.loader.file
            .then( file => new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
                        this._initRequest();
                        this._initListeners( resolve, reject, file );
                        this._sendRequest( file );
                        } ) );
    }

    // Aborts the upload process.
    abort() {
        if ( this.xhr ) {
            this.xhr.abort();
        }
    }

    // Initializes the XMLHttpRequest object using the URL passed to the constructor.
    _initRequest() {

        const xhr = this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Note that your request may look different. It is up to you and your editor
        // integration to choose the right communication channel. This example uses
        // a POST request with JSON as a data structure but your configuration
        // could be different.
        xhr.open( 'POST', '/uploadScript.php', true );
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
    }

    // Initializes XMLHttpRequest listeners.
    _initListeners( resolve, reject, file ) {

        const xhr = this.xhr;
        const loader = this.loader;
        const genericErrorText = `Couldn't upload file: ${ file.name }.`;

        xhr.addEventListener( 'error', () => reject( genericErrorText ) );
        xhr.addEventListener( 'abort', () => reject() );
        xhr.addEventListener( 'load', () => {

                const response = xhr.response.url;
            

                // This example assumes the XHR server's "response" object will come with
                // an "error" which has its own "message" that can be passed to reject()
                // in the upload promise.
                //
                // Your integration may handle upload errors in a different way so make sure
                // it is done properly. The reject() function must be called when the upload fails.
                if ( !response || response.error ) {
                    return reject( response && response.error ? response.error.message : genericErrorText );
                }

                // If the upload is successful, resolve the upload promise with an object containing
                // at least the "default" URL, pointing to the image on the server.
                // This URL will be used to display the image in the content. Learn more in the
                // UploadAdapter#upload documentation.
                resolve( {
                    default: response
                    } );
                } );

        // Upload progress when it is supported. The file loader has the #uploadTotal and #uploaded
        // properties which are used e.g. to display the upload progress bar in the editor
        // user interface.
        if ( xhr.upload ) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener( 'progress', evt => {
                    if ( evt.lengthComputable ) {
                    loader.uploadTotal = evt.total;
                    loader.uploaded = evt.loaded;
                    }
                    } );
        }
    }

    // Prepares the data and sends the request.
    _sendRequest( file ) {
        // Prepare the form data.
        const data = new FormData();

        data.append( 'fileToUpload', file );

        // Important note: This is the right place to implement security mechanisms
        // like authentication and CSRF protection. For instance, you can use
        // XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader() to set the request headers containing
        // the CSRF token generated earlier by your application.

        // Send the request.
        this.xhr.send( data );
    }
}

function MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin( editor ) {
    editor.plugins.get( 'FileRepository' ).createUploadAdapter = ( loader ) => {
        // Configure the URL to the upload script in your back-end here!
        return new MyUploadAdapter( loader );
    };
}

ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#message' ), {
extraPlugins: [ MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin ]
} )
.catch( error => {
        console.log( error );
} );
```

And here is the uploadScript in php:

```
<?php

$uploaddir = "uploadImages\\";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);

echo "{\"url\":\"meer.jpg\"}";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

first verify the file uploaded or not

in you uploadScript in php:
$file_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
echo $file_name;

if return the file name means file uploaded correctly

i'm little doubt here

```
$uploaddir = "uploadImages\\";
```

please change to

```
$uploaddir = "uploadImages/";
```

hope it that will help

your js is correct as per ckeditor doc